# Trying to webscrape an unchanging URL with data spread over pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl

I am new to Webscraping. The url I am working with is this (https://tsmc.tripura.gov.in/doc_list). At present, I am able to extract data from the first page. Since, the url is unchanging, I don't have an identifier for the other pages to create a loop for data table extraction.
Here is my code:

```
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("RCurl")
install.packages("rlist")
install.packages("bitops")
library(bitops)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url1<- getURL("https://tsmc.tripura.gov.in/doc_list",.opts = 
list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
table1<- readHTMLTable(url1)
table1<- list.clean(table1, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
n.rows <- unlist(lapply(table1, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
table1[[which.max(n.rows)]]
View(table1)
table11= table1[["NULL"]]
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I have been seeing this combination of packages in the context of scraping quite a bit recently. Did you happen to pick this up from a particular resource and if so can you point me to it?

Comment: Having said ^^. Welcome to SO. First question, why are you not just grabbing the CSV file they provide? It's a BIG ORANGE BUTTON right at the bottom of the page and contains over 4,000 records? Second, you have a full pagination bar, so where do get the idea you can't find a target to pull to get other pages? Finally, this is a well-worn topic in the R tag. What other SO questions did you research and what — between them — made this site so special? Please respect the time and effort of SO contributors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try this solution:

```
url <- "https://tsmc.tripura.gov.in/doc_list?page="
sq <- seq(1, 30) # There appears to be 30 pages so we create a sequence of 1:30 results

links <- paste0(url, sq) #Paste the sequence after the url "page="

store <- NULL
tbl <- NULL

library(rvest) #extract the tables
for(i in links){
  store[[i]] = read_html(i)
  tbl[[i]] = html_table(store[[i]])
}

library(plyr)
df <- ldply(tbl, data.frame) #combine the list of data frames into one large data frame
df$`.id` <- gsub("https://tsmc.tripura.gov.in/doc_list?page=", " ", df$`.id`, fixed = TRUE)
```

Which gives 846 observations across 8 variables.

EDIT: I found that the first `url` does not have a sequence. In order to add the first page and `rbind` it with the rest of the data use the following:

```
firsturl <- "https://tsmc.tripura.gov.in/doc_list"

first_store = read_html(firsturl)
first_tbl = html_table(first_store)
first_df <- as.data.frame(first_tbl)
first_df$`.id` <- 0


df2 <- rbind(first_df, df)
```

Comment: but…but… _there's a CSV with all the data available_ and it has over 4,000 entries.

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly! i just wanted to know how you identified that the first url did not have a sequence.

Comment: I am aware that the csv is available but I wanted to learn this method as well. Really want to get good at this:D